# image upload name not insert in to databse

Tags: php

My html code like this i am having problem with image name image name is not inserted into database table where do i make mistake i do not know in php.ini file_upload is already on still i am facing problem with file upload..

```
<form action="category.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" value="{$category_id}" name="category_id">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Category Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category_nm" id="category_nm" placeholder="Enter Category Name" value="{$category_nm}" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="cat_img">File input</label>
                  <input type="file" id="cat_img" name="cat_img">
                  <p class="help-block">Please Select Category Image. (Image Type :- JPG, JPEG, PNG )</p>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
              </div><!-- /.box-footer-->
            </form>
```

My php file upload code is like this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
        {
          $category_nm = isset($_POST['category_nm']) ?  $_POST['category_nm'] : '';
          $cat_img     = isset($_POST['cat_img']) ?  $_POST['cat_img'] : '';

          $insertCat = "INSERT INTO category(category_nm,cat_img) 
                                 VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string ($category_nm)."',
                                          '".mysql_real_escape_string ($cat_img)."')";
        $insertCatRes = mysql_query($insertCat);
        if($insertCatRes)
        {
          $target_dir = "_cat_img/";
          $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["cat_img"]["name"]);
          $uploadOk = 1;
          $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
          if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
          {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["cat_img"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) 
            {
              echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
              $uploadOk = 1;
            } 
            else
            {
              echo "File is not an image.";
              $uploadOk = 0;
            }
          }

          // Check file size
          if ($_FILES["cat_img"]["size"] > 500000)
          {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
          }
          // Allow certain file formats
          if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
          {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
          }
            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
          if ($uploadOk == 0) 
          {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
          }
          else 
          {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cat_img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
            {
              echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["cat_img"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            }
            else
            {
              echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
           //header("Location:category.php");   
        }

      }
```

Comment: `$cat_img     = isset($_POST['cat_img']) ?  $_POST['cat_img'] : '';` look at that again.

Comment: thanks i got my answer

Answer (score 1):

Files are posted with `$_FILES` not with `$_POST`.

Change

```
$cat_img = isset($_POST['cat_img']) ? $_POST['cat_img']: '';
```

To

```
$cat_img = isset($_FILES['cat_img']['name']) ? $_FILES['cat_img']['name'] : '';
```